# Error while crawling LOB contents in SP 2013:Could not find default endpoint references contract in ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: 2013, web-services, crawling, bdc-model

I created BDC Model in SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2013. I am retrieving data from external data source using Web Service in ReadList method. Using this external content type (BDC Model) i created one external list and it is populating with data.
I created content source in search service application using this BDC Model and when crawled this content source i am getting the below error.

**Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.RuntimeException MethodInstance with Name 'ReadList' on Entity (External Content Type) with Name 'Entity1' in Namespace 'bcsex.BdcModel1' failed unexpectedly. The failure occurred in method 'ReadList' defined in class 'bcsex.BdcModel1.EntityService1' with the message 'Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.Service1Soap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.**

I included the bindings and client end point configuration settings in web.config file located at \Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Port_Number, but still getting the same error.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue resolved by including the bindings and client end point configuration settings in machine.config file located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\ and also restarted the server after config changes.